# " Invalid or incomplete introspection result" error when i load the graphql endpoint for my django project

Tags: django, django-models, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a Django project where I am using Graphql but after writing out only one mutation, the /graphql does not run properly, throwing the following error.

```
 {
  "message": "Invalid or incomplete introspection result. Ensure that you are passing \"data\" property of introspection response and no \"errors\" was returned alongside: null.",
  "stack": "r@https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/graphiql@1.0.3/graphiql.min.js:1:24583\nur@https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/graphiql@1.0.3/graphiql.min.js:1:326896\nwindow.GraphiQL</</s/value/<@https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/graphiql@1.0.3/graphiql.min.js:7:48325\n"
}
```

How can I fix this ???
Here is my main schema

```
import graphene


import accounts.schema



class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    pass



class Mutation(accounts.schema.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass



schema = graphene.Schema()
```

Here is my account schema file

```
    import graphene

from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from .models import CustomUser



class CustomUserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser


class CustomUserInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    full_legal_name = graphene.String(required=True)
    title = graphene.String(required=True)
    email = graphene.String(required=True)
    phone_number = graphene.String(required=True)
    physical_address = graphene.String(required=True)
    password = graphene.String(required=True)
    confirm_password = graphene.String(required=True)
    role = graphene.String(required=True)

class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    user = graphene.Field(CustomUserType)

    class Arguments:
        user_data = CustomUserInput(required=True)
        

    def mutate(self, info, user_data=None):
        user = CustomUser(
            email=user_data.email,
            full_legal_name=user_data.full_legal_name,
            title=user_data.title,
            phone_number=user_data.phone_number,
            physical_address=user_data.physical_address,
            password=user_data.password,
            confirm_password=user_data.confirm_password,
            role=user_data.role
        )
        if user.password != user.confirm_password:
            raise Exception("Passwords do not match!")
        else:
            user.set_password(user_data.password)
        user.save()

        return CreateUser(user=user)


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()
```

And my model.py file which I used to build out the schema.

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    TITLES = (
        ('Mr', 'Mr'),
        ('Mrs', 'Mrs')
    )

    ROLES = (
        ('school_admin', 'school_admin'),
        ('app_admin', 'app_admin'),
        ('school_staff', 'school_staff')
     )

    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, max_length=255, verbose_name='email address')
    full_legal_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='full legal name')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='title')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='phone number')
    physical_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='physical address')
    confirm_password = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100, verbose_name='confirmation')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLES, verbose_name='role')

    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
```

How can I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add a sample query and pass both the query and the mutation to graphene.Schema as shown below.

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
     hello = graphene.String(default_value="Hi!")


class Mutation(accounts.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
     pass


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```